# Disabling Email features in limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

I am using limesurvey for my personal purposes, in an intranet. I dont have a mail server installed in the system. Now, whenever i enable public registration, after the registration, an error page is shown,saying email not sent. How can I make the screen to advance to survey? I dont want to install a mail server, and want to cpmpletely disable all email features.

I already tried removing contents from mail templates and disable confirmation mail in settings. But that is not helping me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need tokens but do need "registration", you can simply place mandatory email and name questions in the survey.